# Trying to create a tennis ball in CSS, but some elements do not appear

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS for a tennis ball with eyes from codepen.io (https://codepen.io/Mohamed-Ayman/pen/ajzKXJ):

```
.tennis,
.lefteye,
.righteye {
  position: absolute;
}


.tennis {
  width:70px;
  height:70px;
  background:#A0EA11;
  border-radius:50%;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  overflow:hidden;
  box-shadow:0px 15px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  animation:jump .8s linear infinite alternate;
  &:before,
  &:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    left:12px;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    background:transparent;
    border:3px solid #FFF;
    border-radius:50%;
  }
  &:before {top:-28px;}
  &:after {bottom:-28px;}

  .lefteye {
    top:50%;
    left:30%;
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    background:#FFF;
    border-radius:50%;
    &:before {
      content:'';
      position: absolute;
      top:7px;
      right:1px;
      background:#000;
      width:6px;
      height:6px;
      border-radius:50%;
    }
  }
  .righteye {
    top:50%;
    right:15%;
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    background:#FFF;
    border-radius:50%;
    &:before {
      content:'';
      position: absolute;
      top:7px;
      right:1px;
      background:#000;
      width:6px;
      height:6px;
      border-radius:50%;
      //animation:move 2s ease infinite alternate;
    }
  }
}



@keyframes jump {
  0% {
    top:50%;
  }
  100% {
    top:30%;
    box-shadow:0px 45px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  }
}
```

The problem is that, instead of looking like in the first photo, it looks like in the second, so the eyes do not appear. I tried changing a little bit the CSS, but the output is not different. If I close the brackets for the "tennis" element before the "lefteye" and "righteye", the shape of the eyes does appear, but the small black circles from inside them do not appear. 
Does anyone know what is wrong? And what can I do ?

[image]
[image]

Comment: your codepen is wokring fine

Comment: but it looks completely different, take a look at my second pic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are intrested here is a solution with one element easy to handle for your animation:

```css
.tennis {
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   margin:20px;
   border-radius:50%;
   background:
      /*left eye*/
      radial-gradient(farthest-side,#000 99%,transparent 100%) calc(50% - 15px) calc(50% + 5px)/9px 9px,
      radial-gradient(farthest-side,#fff 99%,transparent 100%) calc(50% - 20px) 50%            /20px 20px,
      /*right eye*/
      radial-gradient(farthest-side,#000 99%,transparent 100%) calc(50% + 25px) calc(50% + 5px)/9px 9px,
      radial-gradient(farthest-side,#fff 99%,transparent 100%) calc(50% + 20px) 50%            /20px 20px,
      /*top half circle */
      radial-gradient(circle 35px at top,
            transparent calc(100% - 8px),
            #fff calc(100% - 7px) 99%,transparent 100%) top    -5px left 0,
      /*bottom half circle */
      radial-gradient(circle 35px at bottom,
            transparent calc(100% - 8px),
            #fff calc(100% - 7px) 99%,transparent 100%) bottom -5px left 0,
      /*main background*/      
      #A0EA11;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    box-shadow:0px 15px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #a7a446;
}
```

```html
<div class="tennis"></div>
```

[image: CSS tennis ball]

Comment: it looks perfect now, but it does not move anymore and I tried to add animation: jump and then the jump code from the codepen.io, but it seems that it does not move :))

Comment: @Maria1995 I didn't add the move because I thought it would be trivial. Don't forget to set the position to absolute before adding the jump

Comment: sorry, I am front end beginner :D I do back end mostly...thanks a lot !! I missed that "position" thing